# error message "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a music player to a blog for school and this is the coding I'm using and I keep getting an error message that says The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://scmplayer.net/script.js" 
data-config="{'skin':'skins/cyber/skin.css','volume':50,'autoplay':false,'shuffle':true,'repeat':1,'placement':'top','showplaylist':true,'playlist':[{'title':'(One Of Those) Crazy Girls - Paramore','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cn97UuH7vZY'},{'title':'.weighted. - frnkiero and the cellabration','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ei6ueIN0MI'},{'title':'Action Cat - Gerard Way','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NK86mayKTY'},{'title':'Always Attract - You Me At Six','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U19pXU4eZiU'},{'title':'Boys/Boys/Girls - Panic! At The Disco','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yk8jV7r6VMk'},{'title':'Helena (Acoustic) - My Chemical Romance','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Y5J6V2pwcU'},{'title':'Hell Above - Pierce the Veil','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz6mIeOXOOA'},{'title':'Homesick - A Day To Remember','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNOITmHPaQA'},{'title':'Hospital For Souls - Bring Me the Horizon','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9IXhGl1kWc'},{'title':'I Don%27t Care - Fall Out Boy','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90MxRK0P1u0'},{'title':'I%27m Low On Gas and You Need A Jacket - Pierce The Veil','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMoaOL9dHPU'},{'title':'Miles Away - Memphis May Fire (feat. Kellin Quinn)','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3Qz5P-YMdk'},{'title':'Misery Business - Paramore','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCyGvGEtOwc'},{'title':'Miss Missing You - Fall Out Boy','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9cIfh_6_-o'},{'title':'Poetic Tragedy - The Used','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1fas5QeHgA'},{'title':'Remembering Sunday - All Time Low','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEBrjCasRSQ'},{'title':'Siberia (Acoustic) - Lights','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xdbnA7BarU'},{'title':'The Bird And The Worm - The Used','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zv9zDC5HaKs'},{'title':'The Phoenix - Fall Out Boy','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKAEj6o5PFM'},{'title':'This Is Gospel','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGE381tbQa8'}]}" ></script>
<!-- SCM Music Player script end -->
```

And it wont let me

Comment: What is giving you that error message?

Comment: @epascarello I have to use blogger as the platform, so it's blogger's customization by html code